# Is there a calculation to determine reflected sound from a brick wall?

Tags: acoustics, everyday-life

A new house is being built directly at the bottom of my garden (which is currently open countryside). There will be a $7.5 m$ high wall at the end of this new house which is facing my property. In total it is $50 m^2$ of brick with two very small windows. I’m concerned that this will reflect (and amplify?) any sounds generated. Am I correct in this assumption and is there a calculation to determine said sounds that I can give to the planners? Any help would be appreciated. Keep it simple please!

Answer (score 1):

As asked, I'll keep it simple.
An echo can not amplify sound, so your wall will never amplify. If the wall is closer than 17.5m or a close figure, it is impossible for you to hear a resound. If it's not so close, there is a possibility you will hear faint echoes but not strong enough to disturb you. Because in an open space like that, waves scatter and sound energy is absorbed by nearby absorptive objects.

Comment: What is the significance of 17.5m? What is a "resound"? Why will it be impossible to hear a "resound" in these circumstances?

Comment: The answer lies in the fact that to hear a resound(an echo), the reflected sound and actual sound must be 0.1s apart because otherwise our brain can not perceive them differently.  Now i put in the avg speed of sound (350m/s), and the time as 0.1s, and the minimum distance would be  35m (don't forget to divide the answer by 2 because sound takes double the real distance - to go and come back. Net answer: 35/2 = 17.5

Comment: The distance is actually 34m but from what you’re saying, it won’t really be an issue. Just visual then!  Thanks for taking the time to answer guys, that’s really good of you.

Comment: @Theinfinity I see. But is the question asking in what circumstances an echo will be heard distinctly? The sound and its reflection will still be heard together, louder than the sound alone, if the wall is less than 17.5m away.

Comment: @sammy gerbil But how much amplification can it produce, I personally feel that the amplification wouldn't be quite detectable whereas echoes are. Which is more pleasant screaming in an empty but small room or a huge hall where you can hear echoes. Actually now I feel this question doesn't require  so much analysis b.coz anything wouldn't matter much on such huge scale.

Comment: @Theinfinity The amplification which I am thinking of is hearing the echo and the original sound at about the same time, out of phase but overlapping in time. I recall once eating some crisps (chips) at a bus stop and hearing the crunches in my mouth much louder at one spot than any other. It was as though someone turned on a loudspeaker inside my head. When I looked up directly above the 'sweet spot' there was a concave reflector - the back of an overhead light for which the convex translucent front had been removed by vandals. It focussed the sound back toward my head.